# How to handle urls in load runner?

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I have created/recorded a script in Vugen, however the the URL of the site has been changed recently. Is there any way just by replacing the url with a parameter works?

I have tried by replacing url with parameters, the new URL is
`http://xsx.xxx.xsx.xxx/test99`

Yhe parameters I have tried are below:

`NewUrl: http://xsx.xxx.xsx.xxx/`

`Newhos: test99`

I have replaced all in the script and when I run it I get the following error:

> Error -27651: Attempted read from an unconnected socket (empty response, no HTTP headers received). URL="http://xsx.xxx.xsx.xxx/scripts/uiServer.dll"

What is the solution for this? Should i record again with the new URL ?

Thanks.

Comment: If you replaced manually then there might be a problem. You should have replaced with the automatic replacement functionality in VuGen.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I've understood what you're asking for, so here goes. If it's only the URL that has changed and not the content of the site which you might require later on in your script that this is fairly simple to do.

As you have created the new parameters ensure that they are getting the data from the same DAT file. I.e. newurl.dat which contains the following: 
newurl,newhost
http://xsx.xxx.xsx.xxx/,test99

and assign the parameters to the correct column and have the newhost set to sameline as newurl. This way it’s easier to maintain I believe.

Now that the parameters have been created and properly assigned in your script you’ll need to change the url your trying to change from:

http://xsx.xxx.xsx.xxx/oldtest to {newurl}{newhost}

this needs to be done for all instances where the change has occurred.

Hope this helps with your problem you’re having.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that the build level has not also changed at the same time as the host?  If so then your new instance may be out of synch with the request model of the scripts built using an earlier build.   Developers have a habit of including items below the scenes that do affect the site visually but change the structure of the requests.   The error you are receiving is common when you attempt to continue a conversation on a dead connection resulting from a missed dynamic session component which may have been added in the last build.

When in doubt quickly record the second site and take a look at the differences in the requests, even to the point of using WinDiff (included in LoadRunner) for this purpose.